# Add own custom option and display on sales order in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to display my custom option in.

> app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\order\view\items\renderer\default.phtml

Database information:

**Table Name :**   sales_flat_order_item

**Row_name :** product_options

value :

> a:2:{s:15:"info_buyRequest";a:4:{s:4:"uenc";s:96:"aHR0cDovL2xvY2FsaG9zdC9wNi9kaWFtb25kcy9wcm9kdWN0L2FkZHRvY2FydC9wcm9kdWN0LzI5NzQ2L3NpemUvJTIwNy41";s:7:"product";s:5:"29746";s:8:"form_key";s:16:"pNUqrQJkKIWq5PTC";s:3:"qty";i:1;}s:9:**"ring_size";s:11:"s:4:" 7.5";"**;}

"ring_size" is my custom option added while make order.
Can you let me know How I can display it on admin order.

Comment: you can fetch options from item data.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Please read Question first. I need to display "ring_size". Am I clear?

Comment: If you added it as custom options, then magento it seld display them in order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was added **"ring_size"** as a custom option. I want to display it in admin->Sales->order. After search and implement a solution. I hope this will help to lot off people.

**Frontend**

\Testingorder\etc\config.xml

```
<checkout_cart_product_add_after> 
    <observers>
      <checkout_cart_product_add_after_handler> 
        <type>model</type> 
        <class>testingorder/observer</class> 
        <method>checkoutCartProductAddAfter</method> 
        <args></args> 
      </checkout_cart_product_add_after_handler>
    </observers>
</checkout_cart_product_add_after>
```

\Testingorder\Model\Observer.php

```
public function checkoutCartProductAddAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $item = $observer->getEvent()->getQuoteItem();
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
    $ringSize = Mage::getModel('core/session')->getRingSize();
    if ($ringSize) {
        $item->addOption(array(
            "item_id" => $item->getId(),
            "product_id" => $item->getProduct()->getId(),
            "code" => "ring_size",
            "value" => serialize($ringSize)
        ));
        $item->save();
    }
}
```

**Adminhtml**

\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\sales\items\column\name.phtml

```
<?php if($custom_options = unserialize($_item->getproduct_options())):
    if($ring_size = unserialize($custom_options['ring_size'])): ?>
        <dl class="item-options">
            <dt><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Ring Size') ?></dt>
            <dd><?php echo '<pre>';print_r($ring_size); ?></dd>
        </dl>
    <?php   endif;
endif; ?>
```